# Conditionally appending in the list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have 'n' lists let's say:

```
L1=[1,2,3,4]
L2=[1,2,4,5]
L3=[2,1,3,4]
L4=[4,3,1,2]
L5=[2,1,4,5]
L6=[1,3,4,5]
```

Expected result:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,1,3,4],[4,3,1,2],[1,3,4,5]]
```

I want the code to look for first two elements in every list and append only if both these two elements aren't same:

Comment: Your question describes what you want to do. What exactly do you need *help with* to do this?

Comment: The logic for the same.

Comment: Yes I know those things. I have tried few things and Have been hitting walls all the time

Comment: Well then [edit] your question and show what you have tried so we can help you with that.

Comment: I cant copy paste code from my working computer the transfer is tracked and might jeopardize my employment. Hence typing from phone and usually this forum have been generous enough to write the code for me. Sorry if it wasn't upto your expectation but I cant type the code with my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the desired output:

```
L1=[1,2,3,4]
L2=[1,2,4,5]
L3=[2,1,3,4]
L4=[4,3,1,2]
L5=[2,1,4,5]
L6=[1,3,4,5]

output = []
tmp_set = set()
for list_ in [L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6]:
    x1, x2 = list_[:2]
    if not (x1, x2) in tmp_set:
        tmp_set.add((x1, x2))
        output.append(list_)
print(output)

#[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 3, 4], [4, 3, 1, 2], [1, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I have never worked with sets. Could you please forward me some documents on the same. It is very powerful

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to mark the answer as 'accepted'.
Documentation on python.org: [Set Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). On realpython.com: [Sets in Python](https://realpython.com/python-sets/)

Answer (score -1):

How is this?

```
class SpecialList(list):
    def __init__(self, x=[]):
        self.memory = set()
        super().__init__(x)
    def append(self, x):
        x1, x2 = x[:2]
        if not (x1, x2) in self.memory:
            self.memory.add((x1, x2))
            super().append(x)

x = SpecialList()
x.append([1,2,3,4])
x.append([1,2,4,5])
x.append([2,1,3,4])
x.append([4,3,1,2])
x.append([2,1,4,5])
x.append([1,3,4,5])

print(x)
```